# Would asking this question be acceptable, or should I deal with the older question?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I have a question along the lines of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457289/how-to-programmably-set-the-footable-js-current-page)

While I have been searching for a day or so now for an answer to this question, I don't feel I can re-ask this question here, since one already exists.

My problem comes in the form of this question is one line, and very unlikely to get answered. I don't want to edit it in case their specific situation is differing from mine, but I want to ask my own question.

In this case, would it be alright to ask my own question on the topic? Or should I comment/edit on the original question with hopes of getting an answer that will assist me?

Comment: I don't know what the popular opinion will be, but I'd say given how brief that question is, it has attracted no attention, and the OP hasn't been active in a month - post away.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards, especially since I have a more specific way to ask it, but I felt I should save everyone a bit of headache and see if I'd have any luck in not getting closed as a duplicate first.

Comment: Edit or post, whatever makes you feel more comfortable, that question could use your input.

Comment: @iwein I posted my own. I just have this feeling that if they had an actual issue with it, it is quite possible it is with different circumstances than mine, and I would hate to get them a different answer than what they were truly looking for. That said, I hope they decide to come back and edit their question to get an answer to their own problem.