# Is it appropriate to ask a new question if a duplicate already exist?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Someone already asked a question - [Load Default chrome profile with Webdriverjs Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779027/load-default-chrome-profile-with-webdriverjs-selenium) - that is very similar to mine, but have no answer till now.

In my (still in drafts) question I add some links / code / references / attempts... In compare to other question, my question contains more information.

- Chances that someone will answer old question are low.
- Chances that someone will answer my new question are relatively high.

However, if I ask a new one someone will likely mention "possible duplicate"...

What would a StackExchange ninja do in this situation?

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300392/1380752

Comment: Your question won't be closed as a duplicate of that one, just to note. To close a question as a duplicate of another, the original question must have an upvoted or accepted answer. Given the age of that question, if you're positive you can write a better question, I would say go for it. (Note that I encountered a [very similar situation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262506) myself, though the question that was pre-existing was deleted shortly after by the meta effect.)

Comment: I suggest a new question because, to me, if you add much to that question I would think you really risk adding details that don't actually pertain to the OP's situation and could drive the question in an ever so slightly different direction, since their question is incredibly short and does not have much detail at all. (I don't have experience in the technology involved, so take that with a grain of salt.)

Comment: For completeness - the was one another (now removed) answer - http://i.imgur.com/3TkdEcA.png (I happened to have that browser window open)... I think it's worth to acknowledge arguments of both sides.

Comment: @Michal Stefanow:- I think, now you posted the answer to the original question, Is that solved your problem

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName - the original question used slightly different syntax and by trying it I got unstuck. Then I ran into some other problems. My unasked question: https://gist.github.com/stefek99/87533df1b35ac5df0d85 (for posterity)

Answer (score 5):

Better not to ask same question again, if it is exactly the same.

If you have enough reputation (in this case you do), you can add a bounty to question.

If you have more information as you do more research, edit the existing question to include example or some sort of progress(**without changing the intention of question**), then this question goes to front page, and becomes active, and the chances of getting an answer increase.