# How to rephrase someone else's question?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

This question is similar to [How to rephrase a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329845/how-to-rephrase-a-question).

I've encountered a problem recently and found that someone else has asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501959/why-is-the-global-step-not-incrementing-in-custom-tensorflow-model-function). It took a while to see that the problem was the exact same one as mine. I think that there's a lot of redundant code to be removed. Editing the question would almost be like asking a totally new question. I'd like to improve this question and give a thorough answer as well. Should I:

1. Ask a new question and answer (Q & A style).
2. Make major edits to the question and answer it.

Comment: 3. Ask a new question and close as duplicate?

Comment: I'm a fan of option 2.

Comment: Probably a more common situation - someone else asks a _poorly phrased question_ that sucks all the search-winds out of yours.

Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories does (look at the highest voted answer vs. the accepted answer) even though the OP is _rebasing_

Compare with the generic search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22merge+unrelated+histories%22 where several other questions phrased much more aptly aren't getting any oxygen.

Comment: Carefully removing redundant code seems like the right option, especially if all the answers don't address the redundant code and the question can safely be boiled down to a MRE form.

Comment: @qneill Which one of those was accepted. I don't see any acceptance in the timeline for that question

Comment: @TylerH yeah you are right, there's no accepted answer yet.  I guess my statement was a little orthogonal to this discussion.  They both deal with "questions that have issues that need addressing"  not necessarily because of the content, but because of how SO mechanisms expect a threaded, coherent answer and rating systems.   TBH I think it's because the underlying subject matter is complicated (in the case I brought up `git`)